# How to retrieve the cell information for mouseover event in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, mouseover

This question is specific to jqGrid. I learned that we can use `.jqgrow` item with `mouseover` event to retrieve the row information like the following:

```
gridComplete: function () {
  $('.jqgrow').mouseover(function(e) {
    var rowId = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log('You rolled over ' + rowId);
  });
}
```

My question is how can we retrieve the column information, cell name information and cell content information in such an event. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the corresponding HTML or create a jsFiddle?

Comment: If it's a working fiddle then yes it would since it would have both your jQuery AND HTML.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all you don't need to bind `mouseover` on *every row*. It's enough to bind the event **once** *on the whole grid body*. The `e` parameter of the event has `target` property which are initialized to the object which is the origin of the `mouseover` event. So you can use [jQuery.closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the `<td>` and `<tr>` elements which are in the current context. In the way you save memory and improve a little the performance of the solution.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MouseOver.htm) shows how all works in jqGrid. The code which are used is

```
var cm = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
$grid.mouseover(function(e) {
    var $td = $(e.target).closest('td'), $tr = $td.closest('tr.jqgrow'),
        rowId = $tr.attr('id'), ci;
    if (rowId) {
        ci = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($td[0]); // works mostly as $td[0].cellIndex
        if (console) {
            console.log('You rolled over the row with id="' + rowId +
               '" in the column ' + cm[ci].name);
        }
    }
});
```

The output which will be produced by the demo looks like the following

```
LOG: You rolled over the row with id="10" in the column note 
LOG: You rolled over the row with id="10" in the column ship_via 
LOG: You rolled over the row with id="9" in the column ship_via 
LOG: You rolled over the row with id="8" in the column ship_via 
LOG: You rolled over the row with id="8" in the column total 
LOG: You rolled over the row with id="7" in the column total 
LOG: You rolled over the row with id="7" in the column tax 
LOG: You rolled over the row with id="6" in the column tax 
LOG: You rolled over the row with id="6" in the column amount 
LOG: You rolled over the row with id="5" in the column amount 
LOG: You rolled over the row with id="4" in the column amount 
LOG: You rolled over the row with id="4" in the column invdate 
LOG: You rolled over the row with id="3" in the column invdate 
LOG: You rolled over the row with id="3" in the column name 
LOG: You rolled over the row with id="2" in the column name 
LOG: You rolled over the row with id="1" in the column name
```

Comment: thank you Oleg, because of you i again learned a new thing..:)

Comment: This is it. Thank you Oleg for the comprehensive answer. I was thinking to use the cellIndex and go back to colModel to query for the column name but can't get the syntax right (what a poor programmer!). Also, I learned quite a lot from your other posts on jqgrid issues. Thanks.

Comment: @biajee: You are welcome! I found your question absolutely correct and voted it up. I think that the persons who down-voted your question just didn't understood the specific of jqGrid context. By the way `$td.text()` or `$grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowId, ci)` will get you the cell content.

Comment: Thanks for the cell content and also thanks for the up-vote. My bad as well since originally I only put jqgrid in the tag but no where in the body.

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with the `.jqgrow` class.

It has to do with the event, which will set `this` to the `dom element` on which the event occurred.

So meaning if this is the HTML:

```
<div class="jqgrow" data-id="232" id="blabla">Text</div>
```

Then `this` will be that HTML on mouseover. Which you can do anything with you like.

```
$('.jqgrow').mouseover(function(e) {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var dataId = $(this).data('id');
  var html = this;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Probably I am dumb, but I still can't figure out how to get the cell information from `this`. Can you give me an example? Thanks.

Comment: I understand your point for a generic html element. This question is specific to jqgrid. Suppose you have hundred rows and many columns, and they are generated dynamically. How can I catch the hover event on each cell?

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit

OK, didn't see, that you're using **[jQuery grid plug-in](http://www.trirand.com)**.

All columns have an attribute `role="gridcell"` so you could use an attribute-based selector to select all cells:

```
// untested
$('td[role*="gridcell"]').hover();
```

#### First answer

This answer is more like a universal answer to the problem.

I'm assuming you're having a table like this:

```
<table>
        <tr class="jqgrow">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Than you can get information about the columns within the hovered row with:

```
$('.jqgrow').mouseover(function(e) {
    // get all child elements (td, th) in an array
    var cols    = $(this).children();
    console.log('All cols: ' + cols);
    // to retrieve a single column as a jQuery object use '.eq()' - it's like every array redo-indexed 
    console.log('HTML from col 2: ' + cols.eq(1).html());
});
```

This will also work for any other structure like this:

```
<div class="jqrow">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
```

If you want to have a hover on every child element of `.jqrow` you can attach it directly to the children:

```
$('.jqgrow').children().mouseover(function(e) {
    // gets the current 'column'
    var $this = $(this);
});
```

Comment: This is close, but I am still thinking there should be better jqGrid specific solution. Adding a `children()` really helps to get the cellIndex.

Comment: Argh, didn't notice that, sorry. Does the updated answer help?

Comment: Sorry, originally I only put "jqgrid" in the tag. Not in the question body. I will try your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
var cm = jQuery("#list1″).jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
var colName = cm[iCol];
```

Source: http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/get-column-index-name-oncellselect-event-after-column-reorder/

Comment: I think as soon as the column index is retrieved, this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if you can get the row id then its not difficult to get cell information.

var col=$('#grid').jqGrid('getCell',rowId,columnName);

this will give data for that column.