# jqgrid colModel classes

Tags: jquery, class, jqgrid

I have 2 jqgrid, 1 has a QuestionID Column and the other table QuestionID is by it's  row.

```
Grid for Quiz1
rownumber  | QuestionID  | Text
    1      |     12      | What color do you like?
    2      |     15      | Where do you stay?
    3      |     21      | What's your favorite food?
....

Grid2
rownumber  | Student | Q1 *QuestionID = 12* | Q2 *QuestionID = 15* | Q3 *QuestionID = 21*|..
     1     | Mary    |      Correct         |       Wrong          |       Correct       |
     2     | John    |      Wrong           |       Correct        |       Correct       |
     3     | Tim     |      Wrong           |       Wrong          |       Correct       |
```

how do i add colModel properties *classes* for Grid 2 when i mouseover a row in Quiz1.
example if user mouseover row3 = QuestionID = 21 in Quiz1 then in Grid2 the column Q3 will be highlighted.

this is my javascript

```
$("#tbl_Quiz tr").mouseover(function (e) {
         $("#tbl_Grid2 tr").jqGrid('setColProp', 'Q3', { classes: 'colHighlight' });
});
```

the above code is just to test if it will highlight the column, if its successful i would need to dynamically highlight the column.

Is there a way to do this? Really appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you set a class value in your colModel for each column in the second grid, using the ID value for that question.

That way, you can use a jQuery class selector in the mouseover of your first grid to apply an extra "highlight" class entry to all of the matching entries in the second grid (the column that you're looking for). You can also remove this highlight on mouseout.

Just a warning though, I haven't checked into the performance of this method.

```
    var grid = jQuery('#tbl_Quiz');

    //Example grid configuration just to illustrate
    var grid2 = jQuery('#tbl_Grid2');
    grid2.jqGrid({
        data: myData,
        height: 'auto',
        gridview: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        pager: '#pager',
        colNames: ['Student', 'Q1 *QuestionId = 12*', 'Q2 *QuestionId = 15*'
            , 'Q3 *QuestionId = 21*'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'StudentId', index: 'StudentId', key:true, width: 50, 
                sorttype: 'int', hidden: true }
            { name: 'Student', index: 'Student', width: 50, 
                class: 'Student' },
            { name: 'Q1', index: 'Q1', width: 120, class: 'Q12' },
            { name: 'Q2', index: 'Q2', width: 120, class: 'Q15' },
            { name: 'Q3', index: 'Q3', width: 120, class: 'Q21'  }
        ]
    });

grid.mouseover(function (e) {
    //Get the QuestionId value for the currently selected row and highlight columns with that class ID
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762757/how-to-retrieve-the-cell-information-for-mouseover-event-in-jqgrid
    var tr = jQuery(e.target).closest('tr.jqgrow');
    var rowId = tr.attr('id');
    if (rowId) {
        var questionId = grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowId, 'QuestionID');
        jQuery('.Q'+questionId).addClass('highlight');
    }
}

grid.mouseout(function (e) {
    //Get the QuestionId value for the currently selected row and un-highlight columns with that class ID
    var tr = jQuery(e.target).closest('tr.jqgrow');
    var rowId = tr.attr('id');
    if (rowId) {
        var questionId = grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowId, 'QuestionID');
        jQuery('.Q'+questionId).removeClass('highlight');
    }
}
```